# Java multiclient server with RMI

Tags: java, multithreading, rmi

I'm trying to make a multiclient java server for a project school where i can get data or write data on a database(Postgres); i would like to make it with RMI but first of all i don't know if i can make it.

My idea was to make the server class and for every client connection create a thread where i pass to it an istance of the server class, but i think it could consume too many resources. Then,i thought, is it possible to share the same server class instance for every thread? is RMI Thread-safe or should i make it so?

This is only a basic RMI implementation with the database connection statament to connect to it

```
package RMIServer;
import java.rmi.*;
import java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;`your text`


public class TestServer extends UnicastRemoteObject implements Iserver {

    private Statement database = null;

    public TestServer() throws RemoteException {

        super();

        try{
            Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/data", "postgres", "1234");
            database = con.createStatement();
        }catch(SQLException | ClassNotFoundException e ){
            System.out.println("impossibile stabilire una connessione con il database");
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void request(String username, String password)throws SQLException{

        database.execute("INSERT INTO TEST VALUES("+"'"+username+"',"+"'"+password+"')");

    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need any multithreading of your own. An RMI remote obejct is already multithreaded. Just implement the methods in the remote interface and let Nature take its course. RMI isn't thread-safe but you can make it so with `synchronized` whenever necessary. NB `Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver")` has been obsolete since 2006. Remove. NB (2) A `Statement` is not a 'database'. Don't misname variables.